# Wormhole question

Tags: wormholes

first time of posting with very little knowledge of physics, but I am also very curious and eager to understand.

So I was watching interstellar (Christopher Nolan Film)the other day (for the 100th time) and I got to the part of the film where one character explains how the bending of space and time from one point to another would create this hypothetical bridge between two points. He also explains the reason why a wormhole presents as a sphere or more aptly a spherical hole.

In the film, as soon as they enter the wormhole or the 'higher dimension' they travel along this hypothetical corridor and emerge in another star system.

After watching the film, I had a bizarre thought and googled it but found nothing on it, so I thought I'd ask here.

Like a hypothetical wormhole, the Earth and the other planets are also a spheres.

Whilst the physics of a wormhole don't exist on Earth, could it be possible that our planet could be a wormhole but existing with a totally different set of rules.

Obviously we can enter the planets atmosphere and leave with relative ease, but upon entering the earths atmosphere you still have to travel for a period of time before reaching the ground.

My point is that you still have to enter a wormhole and into its atmosphere to get where you are going and if you are returning to Earth, you have to experience similar things.

Maybe we are entering a wormhole with a different set of laws which enables us to see our planet but upon entering it, we can't perceive any speeding up of time. Also allows leaving much easier. Maybe it's a granddad wormhole which has calmed with time.

Or maybe our planet / land mass exists within a wormhole.

Anyway, I know this is full of incorrect thinking but I am having fun with it and just want to see where it goes.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it happens I discussed this in [an answer on the Science Fiction Stack Exchange](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/37779/4144), which as far is we know is where wormholes belong (or at least macroscopic wormholes).

Although the wormhole looks like a sphere, the inside of the wormhole simply doesn't exist. It is as though the surface of the sphere is a mirror, but it reflects you into the other universe. Given this, the surface of the Earth or any other astronomical body cannot be analogous to a wormhole since the inside of the Earth certainly does exist. If the surface of the Earth were like a wormhole then if you tried to go down past the surface you would find you got turned around and were moving up away from the ground again.

Comment: Thanks this was really insightful and I appreciate the fact that you treated my answer seriously.  I am going to head over to the link that you provided. :-)